# In winui3, when I call ContentDialog, it tells me that the current element is already bound to a XamlRoot, but I only call it in one place

Tags: winui-3

In winui3, when I call ContentDialog, it tells me that the current element is already bound to a XamlRoot, but I only call it in one place.

Specific pictures:

[details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2bGL.jpg)

Call mode:

```
                <TextBox x:Name="NumberInput" 
                     Margin="10,-10,10,25"
                     Width="60" 
                     Height="60" 
                     Header=" " 
                     Text="{Binding Limit}"
                     TextChanged="UpdateLimit" />
```

Function specifics:

```
        private async void UpdateLimit(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(NumberInput.Text, out int maxNumber))
            {
                viewModel.Limit = maxNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                ContentDialog Dialog = new ContentDialog
                {
                    Title = "1",
                    Content = "1",
                    CloseButtonText = "1"
                };

                ContentDialogResult result = await Dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
```

I tried looking up the ContentDialog keyword with ctrl+f to confirm that this is the only place I've written it.
And I've learned through new bing's query that this problem doesn't usually occur with only one window, so I don't get it.

I'm new to winui, so sorry if I'm asking a stupid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [XamlRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#set-the-xamlroot).

If you are calling this in a `Page`, you use the page's `XamlRoot`:

```cs
ContentDialog Dialog = new ContentDialog
{
    XamlRoot = this.XamlRoot,
    Title = "1",
    Content = "1",
    CloseButtonText = "1"
};

ContentDialogResult result = await Dialog.ShowAsync();
```

If you are calling this in a `Window`, you use the root element's `XamlRoot`:

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
ContentDialog Dialog = new ContentDialog
{
    XamlRoot = this.RootGrid.XamlRoot,
    Title = "1",
    Content = "1",
    CloseButtonText = "1"
};

ContentDialogResult result = await Dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem has been solved

Comment: Great! If this answer was helpful consider accept it as the answer so we can close this session.